# MM1 queue in Matlab

Tags: matlab, priority-queue

I am a new user of Matlab.

Currently I am learning and playing with M/M/1 queue, and I want to try different simulations in Matlab. I have typed `seExampleMM1QueuingSys` in the command and I have now this beautiful model:

[image: MM1 in Matlab]

So now I want to play with it myself so I can check if the results are the same as I have on paper, here is one task:

- We have an Airport runway that is only for arrivals
- Arriving aircraft joins a single queue for the runway
- Exponentially distributed service time with a rate is 
  µ = 27 arrivals / hour = This means that 27/60 = 0.45(?)
- Poisson arrivals has a rate rate λ = 20 arrivals / hour = This means
  20/60 = 0.33333?

Where do I put numbers for λ and µ in Matlab to check if the results are correct for this exercise?

Comment: Can you click on the knob to see if you can rotate it on the graph?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to rotate on it

Comment: so can you rotate it to whether 0.45 or 0.33333 to get the output you would like to see then? I mean rotate it to the value you want to set, then click on the "run" button on the top of the window tools.

Comment: Yes I can rotate it, but the question is, which of µ or λ  is it? and which place do i put the other one then? Lets say I rotate it to 0.45, where do i input the 0.3333?

Comment: I see. Assume the knob currently exist is your µ, than you would like to duplicate the knob, then link the input of the knob to the system as λ. (Since I have no idea how your system work, I can't really tell how you should link them, but I just assume you should have an idea on how to do that yourself)